# Unity : I can't reference my managed plugin into my test project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Beginning at Unity.

I have made my unity project.
I have added a C# SimAnt.dll project of mine as a managed project into the unity project.
I have created an EditMode test Asset into the unity project.

At this stage, if I can make a test and run it OK.
I can instantiate classes from SimAnt project into the unity project scripts.

But I do not manage to reference SimAnt project into the test project.
I understand where I should do it into the UI:

[image]

But the SimAnt project is not available into the list of projects that I can reference :(

[image]

I have also tried to add the reference directly into the test project via VS.
If I do so, the test project correctly sees the Simant Dll classes as I would expect into VS UI, but the Unity interface still complains about the reference:
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimAnt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried including my SimAnt dll into the .asmdef file of the test project via VS. I am not sure about the syntax though:

[image]

My Assets directory is like this:

[image]

I closed / reopened Unity after adding the reference from VS, no luck.

Any idea?

EDIT: requested screenshots of the editor:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your dll in the plugins folder. It doesnt look like it

Comment: You are using ASMDEFs.  Ensure it has a specific include to the DLL otherwise any code that is part of the ASMDEF won't _"see it"_.

Comment: @BugFinder I tried into a plugins folder and into a DLLs folder, without any difference

Comment: @MickyD
Yes I tried that too (edited in my thread with screenshot).
Not sure about the syntax though. Should I write folders.SimAnt or folders/SimAnt instead?

Comment: Could you show us the dll (location + inspector) you are trying to reference?

Comment: **Don't** edit the ASMDEF file directly.  Simply select it in the **Project** tree and alter the settings in the Inspector GUI.

Comment: @MickyD
that's the prob. My dll is not visible if I use Unity's interface to add it as a reference to the Test project.
I ll add a screen now to the post.

Comment: @derHugo
I have added the screenshot into the main thread.

Comment: If Unity cannot see your plug-in ASMDEF or otherwise then there is no point to editing the ASMDEF via the GUI or text editor.  ASMDEFs are **not** responsible for detecting a plug-in, they merely reference _previously-detected_ plug-ins by Unity proper.  If you hand-crank a ASMDEF to include a non-existent **dodgy.dll** then the reference will either be ignored or the ASMDEF will produce an error. Ensure your DLL is copied to the **Assets\Plugins** folder.  _[Import and configure plug-ins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html)_

Comment: could you include the inspector as well please? Also: Is your DLL compiled for the correct platform? (x86 / x64)

Comment: @MickyD that is not really true if I understand the API correct you linked as well. As I understand it if you place it into a folder structure with `Plugins/<Platform>` it will automatically set some default configurations .. this doesn't mean though that you can not configure your DLL asset manually as well

Comment: @derHugo Incorrect and I wouldn't bother compiling _managed_ plugins for specific x86/x64 platforms especially when you consider Unity is going to re-compile them for whatever deployment platform you choose (x86/x64).  Any CPU works for both.  I find copying my pre-compiled Any CPU .NET plugins to **\Assets\Plugins\MickyD** works fine for my [flight simulator](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/flight-sim-project-update/).  That guide is for native code.

Comment: Here's another guide https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: @MickyD what I was referring to is `Unity automatically applies platform-specific default settings to the plug-in if the plug-in’s path within the Assets folder matches a platform-specific pattern. If the path doesn’t match any pattern, Unity applies the Editor platform default settings to the plug-in.` .. it doesn't mean you can not change the configuration and for which platforms it shall be included via the Inspector of that DLL afterwards

Comment: @MickyD And yours simply worked due to `Unity recognizes specific file and folder types as plug-ins. It can also apply default settings that match the plug-in’s intended platform. `

Comment: @derHugo like I said, those features really only benefit native plug-ins which have to be pre-built for x86/x64.  There's no concept for Any CPU for native code (no one bothers with c++ p-code anymore).  Why bother making it harder for yourself 1) compiling a managed plug-in to x64 2) placing it in a x64 (or equivalent) child folder when any CLR Host can re-compile the assembly for specific x84 or x64 platforms on a needs basis?   Deploying x64 DLLs can sometimes be problematic during dev time.  It wasn't until recently that VS became 64-bit thus tossing that surrogate into the bin.

Comment: @derHugo  , MickyD I have just added screenshots of the editor as per your suggestion.
Looks OK to me.
I am just drag and dropping the dll from my windows directory (where it is compiled) onto the Unity Assets window in Unity interface. Is this how I am supposed to do?
Until now I was dropping the DLL generated in DEBUG. I have just tried to copy the DLL built in Release : same problem.

Comment: Again, I think the DLL is OK cause I can use its classes into the Unity project scripts.
It's only the Test project who misses the reference.

Comment: @A.D. can you pass me the dll?

Comment: @derHugo How shall I pass it to you? I cannot attach non image file into the threads as far as I can see and it is too huge to be just ocpy pasted (50+ classes).
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it!!!!

I was trying to add the plugin into the wrong box.

The plugins (copy pasted DLL) need to be added into the "Assembly references" tab. (2 in screenshot below).

The other projects assemblies need to be added into the "Assembly Definitions References" tab (1 in screenshot below).

[image]

PS : You can add as a plugin the dll file compiled in Debug. It does not have to be the Release compiled file. I had a doubt about this part.